# Embed block into a custom views template

Tags: 7, blocks, theming

I created a custom views template that I have called views-view--page.tpl.php. Now I would like to add a block into the template file.

In my page template file I was able to render a region and do this:

```
<?php print render($page['leftsidebar']); ?>
```

But it seems like this will not work for a views template. I am not the best with PHP so any help would be great!

I'm using Drupal 7.

Comment: http://www.computerminds.co.uk/drupal-code/render-block-programmatically

Comment: what are you trying to achive by this?

Comment: I am using the taxonomy menu module that creates a menu block and I want to call that in my views template.

Answer (score 1):

Using the answer given to me in the comments by @subhojit777 I was able to call it up using this code:

```
<?php 
  $block = block_load('MODULE_NAME', 'DELTA'); 
  $output =      drupal_render(_block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($block)))); 
  print $output; 
?>
```

I don't know if this is the best way, but it's working for now. :)

Comment: Can you put a block inside a custom made block? If so how? This doesn't work.